# Preview a troff file

Tags: preview, troff, groff

So, I have a text file, embedded with troff formatting commands. However, my printer is currently broken, but I want to see what the file looks like, so I can make sure everything is correct. Is there a program that can interpret the commands and show me a file preview? It has to exist. I probably sound really dumb right now, but I cant find info on this matter. somewhere on the Internet it said to use proof or page, but neither of those commands exist on my system.

Comment: Did you really send your file to your printer, just to proof it? See https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=44703 for how to send it to a PostScript file, which can be viewed directly (OX Preview; Ghostscript) or further processed into a PDF.

Comment: I didn't send anything to my printer because it isn't working i'm looking for a way to preview the file in a window. you mentioned Ghost script bu that isn't on my system either

Answer (score 2):

`troff` allows you to output to an ASCII text file with:

```bash
troff -a x.roff
```

If you have `groff` installed, then you can convert it to:

- ASCII text `groff -Tascii x.roff > x.txt`
- HTML `groff -Thtml x.roff > x.html`
- or DVI `groff -Tdvi x.roff > x.dvi`

If you have `ps2pdf`, you can try to convert your postscript file to a PDF (`ps2pdf x.ps`).

There are also online services to convert a ps file to a PDF; such as  http://www.ps2pdf.com.